# parameter name too long in SWAGGER -> can't see dataType example

Tags: swagger

I set a parameter's name quite long ("updateConcessionInConcessionGroupDto") which has the consequence that the example dataType button is too far on the right of the window.
As there is no horizontal scroll, I can't access the example !

How do I enlarge the Swagger window width and/or implement horizontal scroll in the Swagger window ?

Thanks
Arthur

Comment: Which tool do you use to display the Swagger spec - Swagger UI, Swagger Editor, something else? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for answering. See attached screenshot. I'm using Chrome. http://www.clipular.com/c/6634084035198976.png?k=NKKjDQR1BOq6w3s-J0XFduU2ME4